# Extract interactive Map data using Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The page I want to scrape is the following: http://www.city-data.com/

I have no issues whatsoever getting table data using CSS selectors and storing them to pandas. What I'm having issues with, is making code that will navigate specific sections of the maps within specific pages, let's suggest this one as an example: http://www.city-data.com/city/Virginia.html

When at it, we can see a table with 3 columns (Map, Name, Population). When clicking on Map the URL changes to http://www.city-data.com/city/Virginia.html#boxMAPborder, locating the areas of the cities/counties you're interested upon.

This is where it gets messy. The map will show you the areas of interest after clicking on any of the buttons of the "Map" Column. When one of the areas is selected, a pop-up on the right will appear with the information of the county/city:

[image: Buckingham County Panel and Map]

What I want though, requires one extra step: zoom in a bit (not sure the proportion of it), to get County Tracts. Check this one for one of the County Tracts within the same Buckingham County.

[image: One of Buckinhma's County Tracts]

The intention for this is simply to scrape the data from that County Tract panel. In all honesty, that is the easy part, because, at that point, we can see the HTML code edit and therefore we can use CSS selectors to scrape the info from the panel. But all previous steps are a complete mystery to me, the only info I get from the map without clicking on anything is simply something like this or similar:

```
<div class="leaflet-pixi-overlay leaflet-zoom-animated" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(579px, 165px, 0px);"><canvas width="852" height="720" style="width: 852px; height: 720px;" class=""></canvas></div>
```

What would you do in order to achieve this task? Thanks in advance for any help or guidance you can provide.

Comment: all that data is probably being loaded via XHR query, something you can confirm by opening the developer tools (F12) -> Network and filter only XHR.

Comment: @PedroLobito I see. I'm getting an URL defined as: http://pics3.city-data.com/city/js/getBoxes.php?vw=47&svw=47,21,24,37,39,51,54&w=1&c=1&t=t&s=income3&cb=1&zl=8&dv=20186&d=0|1|1|0|1|0
   But to be fair I'm not sure how to use it, I opened it in another browser and couldn't find anything that was close to what the box contents show.

Comment: Emulate the xhr request by using the same headers and you'll have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("http://www.city-data.com/city/Virginia.html#boxMAPborder")

canvas = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="mapOSM"]'))
)

webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(canvas,150,300).click().perform()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[title = "Show more details"]'))
).click()
```

### You can use action class and move to element with offset, this method moves x,y from the top left corner of the element. Here the element is the 'div' element meaning the map area.